# subtract from value from array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to subtract the values from actualAmount - requestingAmount, here the keys Labour Cost and Material Cost are dynamic

```
const actualAmount = [{key: "Labour Cost", value: 550}, {key: "Material Cost", value: 249}];
const requestingAmount = [{Labour Cost: "560"}, {Material Cost: "250"}]

const updatedData = reqCost.map(element => {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(element).map(([key, value]) => {
        let adjustedAmount = parseInt(value) - amfqtyCost;
        return {
        [key]: String(adjustedAmount)
    };
    }));
});

console.log(updatedData); //returns NaN
```

Expected output

```
[{key: "Labour Cost", value: 10}, {key: "Material Cost", value: 1}]
```

Comment: its 560 - 10 = 10 and 250 - 249 = 1

Comment: how do i convert it to integer ?

Comment: are `requestingAmount` element with unique key names ? (could it be `[{'Labour Cost':'560'}, {'Labour Cost':'25'} ,{'Labour Cost':'32'}]` ?)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Map` out of `requestingAmount` and then loop over `actualAmount` to get the desired result.

```js
const actualAmount = [{ key: "Labour Cost", value: 550 }, { key: "Material Cost", value: 249 }],
  requestingAmount = [{ "Labour Cost": "560" }, { "Material Cost": "250" }],
      
  map = new Map(requestingAmount.map((o) => [...Object.keys(o), ...Object.values(o)])),
  res = actualAmount.map(({ key, value }) => ({key, value: map.get(key) - value}));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @Learning Please check if this is helpful. Note: In `requestingAmount` array the keys should be quotes. Let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

may be that...?

```js
const
  actualAmount     = [{ key: 'Labour Cost', value: 550 }, { key: 'Material Cost', value: 249 }] 
, requestingAmount = [{ 'Labour Cost': '560' }, { 'Material Cost': '250' }] 
, result = actualAmount.reduce((r,{key,value})=>
    {
    requestingAmount
      .filter(el=>(key in el))
      .forEach(el=>value=parseInt(el[key],10) -value)
    r.push({key,value})
    return r
    }, [])

console.log(  result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```

OR:

```js
 const
  actualAmount     = [{key:'Labour Cost',value:550},{key:'Material Cost',value:249}] 
, requestingAmount = [{'Labour Cost':'560'},{'Material Cost':'250'}] 
, result = actualAmount.map(({key,value})=>
    {
    value = parseInt(requestingAmount.find(x=>(key in x))[key],10 ) -value
    return ({key,value})
    })

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0;}
```